# Hallar partes que sean iguales de 2 Strings en java

Tags: java, string

quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de comparar 2 Strings en Java de tal manera que se busque no si son iguales, pero si si tienen partes iguales y concatenarlos sin repetir las partes en común.

Ejemplo:

Dados Strings como:
 conf
 onfi
 nfid

El programa me retorne: confid

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado. SO no es un servicio de codificacion gratuiro. Nosotros valoramos los intentos asi que ayudaria que muestres lo que has intentado.

Comment: Lo que pretendes hacer requiere un heurístico bastante complejo. Pueden existir muchas soluciones posibles, dependiendo de lo que pretendas y del grado de precisión que quieras tener (a más precisión, más complejidad).

Una posible solución es que dividas la cadena por sus espacios (con split()) y compares las partes con expresiones regulares. Pero como ya digo, sería una tarea compleja y con muchos detalles a tener en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu enunciado tiene un error, la respuesta tendría que ser: onfid, de lo contrario estás organizando la aparición de caracteres en orden sin repetición, por ejemplo:

```
     String result = "";

     String test = "conf onfi nfid";

     for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {

         if (-1 == result.indexOf(test.charAt(i)) && test.charAt(i) != ' '){
             result += test.charAt(i);
         }
     }
     System.out.println(result);
```